# расположение образа в docker

Tags: docker

Начал устанавливать docker образ, но что-то пошло не так и я прервал установку (закрыл docker терминал) после заполнения ~5Гб диска. Теперь хочу найти и удалить эти файлы.

При выполнении

```
docker info
```

показывает 0 контейнеров

Answer (score 0):

Проблема удаления нескольких гигабайт мусора (неудачной загрузки образа) в виде огромного файла disk.vmdk, расположенного в \username.docker\machine\machines\default\
решилась удалением виртуальной машины с помощью команды

```
docker-machine rm default
```